# Roblox Studio error: Workspace.Driver.OnSeated!:13: attempt to index nil with ''Name''

Tags: lua, roblox

I am having an error with one of my scripts in Roblox Studio. The line that shows that is a problem is Line 13. The script is for basically to weld when somebody sits on the seat, and to start up the TankGUI (Another script that is fine).

```
seat = script.Parent

function onChildAdded(part)
    if (part.className == "Weld") then
        while true do
local           welde = seat:FindFirstChild("SeatWeld")

            if (welde ~= nil) then
local           sitted = welde.Part1.Parent
            end

            if (sitted.Name ~= script.Parent.Owner.Value) then
                if (script.Parent.Owner.Value == "NoOne") then
                    script.Parent.Owner.Value = sitted.Name
                    print ("sitted steal")
                else
                    print ("stolen!!")
local                   shipstealer = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(sitted.Name)
                    if (shipstealer ~= nil) then
                        shipstealer.Humanoid.Jump=true
                    end
                end
            end


            wait(0.2)

            if (welde == nil) then
                print("BreakLoop")
                script.Parent.Owner.Value = "NoOne"
            break end
        end
    end
end

--while true do
--  wait(0.5)
--  script.Parent.Parent.Name=script.Parent.Owner.Value .. "'s Ship"
--end
seat.ChildAdded:connect(onChildAdded)
```

Please excuse any poor co-operation or language barriers I'm having. I'm still a bit new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            if (welde ~= nil) then
local           sitted = welde.Part1.Parent
            end

            if (sitted.Name ~= script.Parent.Owner.Value) then
```

Since you're declaring `sitted` as `local`, it goes out of scope at `end`, so it's gone when you try to use it in that `if`, so you're actually using a nil global variable there. Do this instead:

```
            local sitted
            if (welde ~= nil) then
                sitted = welde.Part1.Parent
            end

            if (sitted.Name ~= script.Parent.Owner.Value) then
```

That way it'll stay in scope until you're actually done with it.

Comment: Uh, I'm having another issue. 
 Workspace.Model.Turret.Driver.OnSeated!:48: Expected 'end' (to close 'function' at line 4), got <eof>

Comment: @qaquahasam Sounds like you accidentally broke something with this fix. Double-check that you didn't accidentally add an extra `function` or delete an `end`.

Comment: Lol, Changed one thing and 2 different scripts broke. I fixed the script now. If I need any more help I'll post a question. Thank you very much for your help!